# Deriving $y$-coordinate

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

Is there any formula for deriving the $y$-coordinate using the $x$-coordinate and the slope in the secp256k1 elliptic curve?

For example:

Calculate the slope:

```
slope = 75359724952757581356787150982223137069297282952438962440225639443485944634025
```

Calculate the new $x$-coordinates:

```
x = 112711660439710606056748659173929673102114977341539408544630613555209775888121
```

Calculate the new $y$-coordinates:

```
y = 25583027980570883691656905877401976406448868254816295069919888960541586679410
```

Each of the above values are valid points in the elliptic curve.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the math behind elliptic curves? Points are defined by an equation which you can find online easily.

Comment: A valid `x` coordinate defines one of two points. It's unclear the slope of what the other given is.

Comment: "Each of the above values are valid points in the elliptic curve" There is one slope and two coordinates. At most there is *one* point defined in the question: $(x, y)$, which begs the question if you've got enough understanding of ECC calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python we have (see [this](https://gist.github.com/nlitsme/c9031c7b9bf6bb009e5a?permalink_comment_id=3909029)):

```
slope = (3 * pow(x, 2, p) * pow(2 * y, -1, p)) % p
```

So

```
y = (3 * pow(x, 2, p) * pow(2 * slope, -1, p)) % p
```

Example

```
p = 2 ** 256 - 2 ** 32 - 2 ** 9 - 2 ** 8 - 2 ** 7 - 2 ** 6 - 2 ** 4 - 1
x = 112711660439710606056748659173929673102114977341539408544630613555209775888121
y = 25583027980570883691656905877401976406448868254816295069919888960541586679410
slope = 75359724952757581356787150982223137069297282952438962440225639443485944634025 
y_ = 3 * pow(x, 2, p) * pow(2 * slope, -1, p) % p
assert y == y_
```

Answer (score 2):

The octet-string-to-ec-point conversion subroutine contains steps that de-compresses a EC point with only x-coordinates into X-Y tuple.

The spec's available on [SECG website](https://secg.org), section 2.3.4 of SEC#1 v2.0